# Where is IAuthenticationFilter interface in asp.net 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I cannot find `IAuthenticationFilter` anymore in asp.net 5. Does anyone know where it is? or has it been removed?

Answer (score 3):

It's called now `IAuthorizationFilter` and is in the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Abstractions` assembly.

Comment: If you use `IAuthorizationFilter`, please implement `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter` too, I had problem with it